# Keep track of changes in LaTeX document

Tags: changes

I see that in documentation for many LaTeX packages authors keep track of changes with a `\changes{}` macro, which then produces a nice index style list of changes. I would like to do the same for edits to my PhD thesis. Is there a way to use this facility, or a similar one, outside the `ltxdoc` document class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `ltxdoc` document class loads the [`doc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) package for the core functionality. The package can be used in other document classes too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{doc}
\RecordChanges

\begin{document}

\changes{v1}{2011/03/24}{Initial version}
Test

\PrintChanges

\end{document}
```

Process the `.glo` file with:

```
> makeindex -s gglo.ist -o <name>.gls <name>.glo
```

For more information refer to the `doc` manual (it can be compiled from the LaTeX2e sources).