# Tools for editing? Redlining? (TeXShop)

Tags: texshop, revision-control, collaboration

As an editor, instructor, and collaborator, I would like to be able to make changes in TeX documents that are tracked so that the other person sees what changes were made.

Word has the capacity to track changes with redlining, and I've heard of a custom version of BaKoMa with this feature.  I use TeXShop but could be convinced to switch.

The packages `todonotes` and `marginpar` are ways to indicate changes to be made, but I'm hoping to track changes in successive versions of a document.

Comment: have you seen [How can you use LaTeX to write a document with other people?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks, excited to learn about the `changes` package.  I searched around other posts, but not long enough and without knowing the best terminology.

@texenthusiast Thanks for the welcome, especially in response to a somewhat redundant question.

@Kurt And thanks for the edit.

Comment: possibly related [“Track changes” in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65453/15717) and [Keep track of changes in LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14181/15717). @BrianHopkins We TeX.SX welcome any newcomer irrespective of type of TeX/LaTeX question,ur most welcome here. [follow this search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changes?sort=votes&pagesize=50) using `changes` tags.