# redline markup in LaTex

Tags: changes

Im trying to create a short list of changes for a document from one revision to another. and only want to show the redlines on a set string.
i.e.

OLD String: I when to the zoo yesterday

NEW String: I went to the zoo today.

Diff string: I went<strike>when</strike> to the zoo <strike>yesterday</strike>today.

Comment: You might be interested in [Keep track of changes in LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14181/5764).

Answer (score 10):

LyX can make exactly that:

[image: MWE]

However, the changes are  stored in their own file format (`.lyx`) but not in the exported LaTeX (`.tex`) source or the PDF.

For a pure LaTeX solution or see the changes in the PDF, you can use the package `changes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}

I \added{went}\deleted{when} to the zoo \added{today}\deleted{yesterday}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

If you want the final PDF version, simply load the package with the `final` option:

```
\usepackage[final]{changes}
```

But also can do something more:
[image: MWE3]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={me}, color=magenta]{Fran}
\definechangesauthor[name={you}, color=red]{you}
\begin{document}
I \added[id=Fran]{went}\deleted[id=Fran]{when} to the zoo 
\added[id=Fran]{today}\deleted[id=you]{yesterday}
\listofchanges
\end{document}
```

See [changes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes) on CTAN for more options.

Another solution:

1) **`old.tex`**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I when to the zoo yesterday
\end{document}
```

2) **`new.tex`**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I went to the zoo today
\end{document}
```

3) In the terminal:

```
texdiff old.tex new.tex diff.tex
```

4) Edit **`diff.tex`**: Add manually some preamble to define `\TLSins` and `\TSLdel` (otherwise you cannot compile the file). The result must be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{ins}{blue} 
\colorlet{del}{red}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\TLSins[1]{\cbstart{}\textcolor{ins}{\uline{#1}}\cbend{}}
\newcommand\TLSdel[1]{\cbdelete{}\textcolor{del}{\sout{#1}}}
\begin{document}
I \protect\TLSdel{when} \protect\TLSins{went} to the zoo \protect\TLSdel{yesterday} \protect\TLSins{today}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE4]

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the [`latexdiff`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff?lang=en) package.

Basically, it is a diff script that you execute

```
latexdiff new.tex old.tex > diff.tex
```

and then you can compile the `diff.tex` and check the differences.

```
% new.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I went to the zoo today.
\end{document}

% old.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I when to the zoo yesterday
\end{document}
```

and the script produces

> [image]