# Track changes option

Tags: formatting

I would like to make some changes in a text I have in latex.

Is there any way to use something like track changes option of the word where someone can see what deleted and in a new color what added in the text?

Comment: Try with `Winmerge` one of a free tool, but more efficient...

Answer (score 1):

1. At the editor level, in LyX:

   <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Change Tracking</kbd> > <kbd>Track Changes</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
2. At the LaTeX level, in any plain text(LaTeX) editor, expliciting manually the type pf changes,  with the  package ...guess ..., yes, `changes`.
3. At the plain text level, comparing differences between two versions. There a lot of options here, from control version system, to GUI to compare two files, but the LaTeX related solution here is `texdiff`.

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245295/11604) there are small examples of use of the three approaches.